# Angular2 routes: can't find external html file

Tags: routes, angular

In angular2, if using internal template in @component, the route works. But if using templateUrl to add external template, it shows an error: can't find resources **.html. Do I need to add something else if using external template?

```
@Component{
   template: ``
}

@Component{
   templateUrl: "**.html"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "external template"?

Comment: Did you check the console to see if it's trying to load the template from the correct path?  Try writing the path from the root directory of your project, instead of using a relative path if that is what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
templateUrl:"rootDir/Components/template.html"
```

My guess is you are using a relative path like this.

```
templateUrl:"./template.html"
```

But without seeing more code it is difficult to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Without routes, if I use "Components/template.html", it works. Do you know why with routes, we need to use absolute path?

Comment: Check this issue for more information: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2383